How to define object type which references keys of a sub-object
I think the best way to describe my question is through a simplified example below:
type Config = {
  txn: {
    makeReference: (formObj: Record<keyof Config["form"], unknown>) => string; // how do I define the `formObj` type
  };
  form: {
    [k: string]: { type: "string"; pattern: RegExp } | { type: "number" }; // to reference keys from this object
  }
};

const config: Config = {
  txn: {
    makeReference: (keys) => `${keys.accountIds}_${keys.subjectId}`, // so that `keys` here has type safety
  },
  form: {
    accountId: { type: "string", pattern: /\w+/ },
    subjectId: { type: "string", pattern: /\w+/ },
    age: { type: "number" },
  }
};

I can't wrap my head around how to use generics here.

You will have to define a generic like the below. The parameter in the generic should be the keys you are looking for. Also, since an index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type, you will have to use a mapped type.
type Config<X extends string> = {
  txn: {
    makeReference: (formObj: Record<X, unknown>) => string; // how do I define the `formObj` type
  };
  form: {
    [k in X]: { type: "string"; pattern: RegExp } | { type: "number" }; // to reference keys from this object
  }
};


const config: Config<'accountId' | 'subjectId' | 'age'> = {
  txn: {
    makeReference: (keys) => `${keys.age}_${keys.subjectId}`, // so that `keys` here has type safety
  },
  form: {
    accountId: { type: "string", pattern: /\w+/ },
    subjectId: { type: "string", pattern: /\w+/ },
    age: { type: "number" },
  }
};

Playground
If you prefer not repeating the key names, you can also move out the object:
type Config<X extends string> = {
  txn: {
    makeReference: (formObj: Record<X, unknown>) => string; // how do I define the `formObj` type
  };
  form: {
    [k in X]: { type: "string"; pattern: RegExp } | { type: "number" }; // to reference keys from this object
  }
};


const form = {
    accountId: { type: "string", pattern: /\w+/ },
    subjectId: { type: "string", pattern: /\w+/ },
    age: { type: "number" },
  } as const;

const config: Config<keyof typeof form> = {
  txn: {
    makeReference: (keys) => `${keys.age}_${keys.subjectId}`, // so that `keys` here has type safety
  },
  form: 
};

Playground
